# Updating existing Object not working in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

In the below code I am trying to update the CommunityUserandRoles object if it already exist, if not insert new object. This code works fine for both insert and update in local environment, but in production its not updating the already existing object and also I am not getting any exception.

Please let me know where its going wrong.

Model Class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name = "CommunityUsersAndRoles")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true, dynamicInsert = true)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class CommunityUserRoles implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Lithium user id.
     */
    @Id
    private long lithiumId;

    /**
     * Lithium user email.
     */
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    /**
     * Lithium user roles.
     */
    private String roles;

    /**
     * Lithium user lastModifiedDate.
     */
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public CommunityUserRoles() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public CommunityUserRoles(long lithiumId, String email, String roles) {
        this.lithiumId = lithiumId;
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = roles;
        this.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    }

    /**
     * Returns lithiumId.
     * 
     * @return Returns the lithiumId.
     */
    public long getLithiumId() {
        return lithiumId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets lithiumId.
     * 
     * @param lithiumId
     *            The lithiumId to set.
     */
    public void setLithiumId(long lithiumId) {
        this.lithiumId = lithiumId;
    }

    /**
     * Returns email.
     * 
     * @return Returns the email.
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * Sets email.
     * 
     * @param email
     *            The email to set.
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * Returns roles.
     * 
     * @return Returns the roles.
     */
    public String getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    /**
     * Sets roles.
     * 
     * @param roles
     *            The roles to set.
     */
    public void setRoles(String roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    /**
     * Returns lastModifiedDate.
     * 
     * @return Returns the lastModifiedDate.
     */
    public Date getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    /**
     * Sets lastModifiedDate.
     * 
     * @param lastModifiedDate
     *            The lastModifiedDate to set.
     */
    public void setLastModifiedDate(Date lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CommunityUserAndRole [lithiumId=" + lithiumId + ", email=" + email + ", roles=" + roles
                + ", lastModifiedDate=" + lastModifiedDate + "]";
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lastModifiedDate == null) ? 0 : lastModifiedDate.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (int) (lithiumId ^ (lithiumId >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((roles == null) ? 0 : roles.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CommunityUserRoles other = (CommunityUserRoles) obj;
        if (email == null) {
            if (other.email != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        if (lastModifiedDate == null) {
            if (other.lastModifiedDate != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastModifiedDate.equals(other.lastModifiedDate))
            return false;
        if (lithiumId != other.lithiumId)
            return false;
        if (roles == null) {
            if (other.roles != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!roles.equals(other.roles))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

DAO Class:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import com.xyz.am.exception.PersistenceLayerException;
import com.xyz.am.persistence.foundation.AbstractGenericHibernateDAO;
import com.xyz.zbc.efg.model.CommunityUserRoles;

public class CommunityUserRolesDAO extends AbstractGenericHibernateDAO<CommunityUserRoles>
        implements ICommunityUserRolesDAO {

    @Override
    public boolean isLithiumIdExist(long lithiumId) throws PersistenceLayerException {
        final DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(getPersistentClass())
                .add(Restrictions.eq("lithiumId", lithiumId));
        if (findByCriteria(detachedCriteria).size() == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public CommunityUserRoles getByEmail(String email) throws PersistenceLayerException {
        final DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(getPersistentClass())
                .add(Restrictions.eq("email", email));
        if (findByCriteria(detachedCriteria).size() == 1) {
            return findByCriteria(detachedCriteria).get(0);
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void insert(final CommunityUserRoles communityUserRoles) throws PersistenceLayerException {
        super.saveOrUpdate(communityUserRoles);
    }

}
```

Service Class method:

```
CommunityUserRoles communityUserRoles = null;
                          if(communityUserRolesDAO.isLithiumIdExist(lithiumUserId)) {
                              communityUserRolesDAO.getByEmail(email)
                              communityUserRoles.setRoles(roles);
                              communityUserRoles.setLastModifiedDate(new Date());


                          }else {
                              communityUserRoles = new CommunityUserRoles();
                              communityUserRoles.setLithiumId(lithiumUserId);
                              communityUserRoles.setEmail(lithiumUsers.get(lithiumUserId).getEmail());
                              communityUserRoles.setRoles(roles);
                              communityUserRoles.setLastModifiedDate(new Date());
                              log.info("New User ID "+lithiumUserId+" Email "+lithiumUsers.get(lithiumUserId).getEmail()+" Roles "+roles+" Date "+new Date());
                          }
                          communityUserRolesDAO.insert(communityUserRoles);
```

Comment: If running the same code on different machine produces distinctly different results, it may be best you focus on finding the differences between the two environments. Did you check the configuration (both hibernate and the DB)? Have you tried profiling the DB to see that the produced query is what you expect it to be?

Comment: @NPras, Both the environments are similar and the configuration too. The produced query is identical and as expected